# How I can to limit decimal numbers of double variable?

Tags: android

How I can to limit decimal numbers of double variable. Indeed I want to change the numbers example 2.34567890 to 2.34 by lower decimal numbers? How to do it? Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
double d = 2.34567890;
DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
double twoDecimal =  Double.valueOf(newFormat.format(d)); // output 2.35
```